# vue js data value return undefined inside method

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to access data value reviews into scroll method . Consoled reviews by console.log(this.reviews). but it always returns undifined;

```
data() {
  return {
    m: '',
    rating: '',
    review: '',
    visibility: '',
    reviews: [],
    page: 1,
  };
},



scroll (page) { 
  $('#profile-edits-more').on("scroll", function() {      
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() + jQuery(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) { 
      var vm = this;
      axios.post('./fetch-reviews?page='+page, {
        m: vm.m,
      })
      .then(response => {
        page +=1; 
        console.log(this.reviews);
      });       
    }
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong `this` try:

```
scroll (page) { 
  var vm = this;
  $('#profile-edits-more').on("scroll", function() {      
    if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() + jQuery(this).innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) { 
      axios.post('./fetch-reviews?page='+page, {
        m: vm.m,
      })
      .then(response => {
        vm.page += 1; 
        console.log(vm.reviews);
      });
    }
  });
},
```

---

UPD:

`$('#profile-edits-more').on("scroll",     ===> function() <===     {`

Expression `function() ...` creates a new scope (with new `this`).
You can also use arrow-methods for such things:

```
scroll(page) { 
  let $el = $('#profile-edits-more');
  $el.on('scroll', () => {
    if ($el.scrollTop() + $el.innerHeight() >= $el.scrollHeight) { 
      axios.post('./fetch-reviews?page='+page, {
        m: this.m,
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.page += 1; 
        console.log(this.reviews);
      });
    }
  });
},
```